# Sails js Create function update input data Object

Tags: sails.js

I have a  data object as below

```
var data = {
  "name" : "Gopal",
  "Age" : "29",
  "Phone" : "982926272"
}
```

Once I pass this "data" Object to create a function to the user model, it omits the "phone" and updates this data object as below.

```
Users.create(data).then(function (){
 console.log("Data Object after create call ",data);
 //Here I am expecting to use "phone" property of "data" object
});
```

////Here is console

```
data  {
  name : Gopal,
  Age : 29,
  createdAt: 2021-02-16T18:52:36.420Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-02-16T18:52:36.420Z,
}
```

Note: My user model doesn't have "phone" property.

I know I can save data in some other object and can use it, but my project is big and migrated from sails 0.12 to 1+.

So if anyone has an idea how I can preserve the "phone" property without creating another object.

Comment: What does the model look like?

Comment: You have to modify your model and add the telephone attribute. Then you have to migrate your database to reflect the new model. I recommend you to backup everything before you try this.    https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models     https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#database-migrations